# dplyr semi_join is not supposed to return duplicates but it does

Tags: r, dplyr

The `CRAN` documentation on the `dplyr` package, in reference to semi_join states: `"A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join will return one row of x for each
matching row of y, where a semi join will never duplicate rows of x"`

The following code, however, seems to give duplicate rows of x in output:

```
x <- data.frame(x1=c(1,1,2), x2=c(2,2,2))
y <- data.frame(x2=c(1,2), x3=c(2,2))
c <- semi_join(x,y)
```

Does this code contradict the documentation, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4):

Your result is what I would from `semi_join` - each row in `x` was returned once.  The joining won't remove duplicate rows of `x`, which may be how you were thinking about this.  For that you may be interested in `distinct` from *dplyr*.

To understand all of this better, it might help to compare what `semi_join` vs `inner_join` does when you define a y dataset with duplicate values of the joining variable.  To show this, I'll add a second `2` to the `x2` variable.

```
y2 <- data.frame(x2=c(1, 2, 2), x3=c(2, 2, 2))
```

Now we can see what happens in `inner_join` vs `semi_join`.  First, we see that `inner_join` duplicates rows; i.e., it returns each row that was in `x` twice.

```
inner_join(x, y2)
Joining by: "x2"
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  2  2
2  1  2  2
3  1  2  2
4  1  2  2
5  2  2  2
6  2  2  2
```

But, as the help page states, `semi_join` does not duplicate rows.  In this case, each row of `x` is returned once even though `y2` had repeated values in the `x2` variable.

```
semi_join(x, y2)
Joining by: "x2"
  x1 x2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  2  2
```

Comment: You are correct in inferring that although semi_join is doing exactly what I wanted, I had misinterpreted "will never duplicate rows of x".  Thanks.

Comment: (+1) it's also better to provie semi_join(y2,x, by ='x2'), which will output only 2 rows, i.e., the part of y2 where y2$x2=2.